# Replacing for-each loop with stream API call in Java

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-stream

Having this code:

```
public Map<Job, Collection<JobTransform>> getPartitioning() {
    Map<Job, Collection<JobTransform>> partitioning = new IdentityHashMap<>();
    for (JobTransform jobTransform : content) {
        Job job = jobTransform.getJob();
        Collection<JobTransform> collection = partitioning.get(job);
        if (collection == null) {
           collection = new LinkedList<>();
           partitioning.put(job, collection);
        }
        collection.add(jobTransform);
    }
    return partitioning;
}
```

and 'content' being a constructor parameter for the class this method is implemented in, how can I convert the for-each loop into code using Stream API in Java? For now I have only

```
content.stream().map(JobTransform::getJob)
```

and I don't know how can I use each job further. Do I use the API wrong? Please help me to improve my code!

Comment: Loop over map content - `map.entrySet().forEach((entry)->{...});`

Comment: That’s the place for the usual disclaimer: you surely don’t want to use a `LinkedList` here, it offers no benefit over the more efficient `ArrayList` in this use case, especially as you are widening it to `Collection` in the result type anyway. You may also think carefully whether you really need an `IdentityHashMap`. Unless `Job` has an equality that you must override, there is no need to use this special map. Most probably, a simple `content.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(JobTransform::getJob))` will do the desired thing, despite not using these specific collection types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
content.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(JobTransform::getJob, IdentityHashMap::new, Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)));
```

This will do exactly the same thing as your non-stream code.